# Forcing invoice.payment_failed: and still succeeding

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, payment

I'm trying to force the invoice.payment_failed: event from the stripe to happen with trial_end: `Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60,` that takes about an hour to create an invoice, I use card 4000000000000341 that in the API itself it indicates that it generates an error in the invoice process, but for some reason in my case it generates invoice.paid which is responsible for the successful payment, in addition to generating other events, where none indicate errors in the payment. I have no idea what's going on. Maybe it's because my plan is metered by usage? I don't know...

I need to force the payment error to test and punish the customer if he doesn't pay the invoice properly.

Comment: Stripe CLI can trigger that event. Did `stripe trigger invoice.payment_failed` not work for you?

Comment: Okay, that worked, but it seems strange to me, because the way I mentioned it confirms the payment, when the card has no funds?

Answer (score 0):

What is the amount of your Invoice ?

If this is metered billing, it bills for the previous period.
If this period is a trial, it shouldn't bill for any amount, regardless of recorded usage during the trial.

If the Invoice amount is 0 (or below Stripe's min range) then no Payment Intent would be generated, and the Invoice would be automatically paid (=>invoice.paid).

I'm not sure there would be much point in using trials with metered billing, since they start free anyway - you might get better results with `billing_cycle_anchor`:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create?lang=node#create_subscription-billing_cycle_anchor